# Есть ли плагин Ajax подгрузки товаров woocommerce?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Нужен плагин для woocommerce для подгузки товаров с помощью кнопки "загрузить еще" не на страницы магазина а например на главной, чтоб я мог вывести допустим несколько категорий и каждую подгрузить по отдельности. Можно на visual composer

Вот к примеру как тут https://in-trendy.ru/
Также встретил реализацию на шаблоне http://www.templatemonsterpreview.com/64369.html

Или как реализовать данную задачу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скачать похожий плагин можно тут:
[Load More Products for WooCommerce](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/load-more-products-for-woocommerce/)

**UPDATE**

Чтобы выводить товары по категориям на произвольной странице через шорткоды и подгружать категории независимо, можно использовать WordPress Infinite Scroll — Ajax Load More плагин. Страница плагина [тут](http://WordPress%20Infinite%20Scroll%20%E2%80%94%20Ajax%20Load%20More). Тестовый пример [тут](http://test.kagg.eu/so701781/).

Comment: нет. Он не подходит. Он загружает товар в магазине а не на главной страницы в категориях

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/187407)

Comment: @cheops по ссылке не ответ на вопрос, а страница загрузки плагина. А весь ответ - в названии этого плагина.

Comment: WordPress Infinite Scroll — Ajax Load разве выводит не только записи?

Comment: Вы хоть потрудитесь по ссылке моего тестового примера пройти, который я создал для вас специально, вместо того, чтобы задавать очередные вопросы. И прочтите описание плагина.

Comment: Спасибо. всё увидел и решил задачу!

Comment: Если ответ оказался полезным, его стоит отметить галочкой внизу, чтобы помочь ориентироваться другим пользователям, ищущим ответ на подобный вопрос.